# How would i go about fading in and out from an array of different words or sentences?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation

So i built a fade in fade out for a label animation in Swift already. But I want to fade in and out from an array of different sentences, so each time fade in and fade out, it would be different staff.

```
   override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         label.alpha = 0
        animatedText()

     }
  func animatedText(){
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: {
            self.label.alpha = 1.0

            }, completion: {
                (Completed: Bool) -> Void in

                UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 2.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
                    self.label.alpha = 0
                    }, completion: {
                         (Completed: Bool) -> Void in

                        self.animatedText()
                })
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

  var sentences = ["The cat sat.", "The rhino ate.", "The monkey laughed", "The zebra ran.", "The fish swam", "The potato grew."]
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    label1.text = sentences[0]
    label2.text = sentences[1]
    label1.alpha = 1.0
    label2.alpha = 0.0

  }
  var counter = 1

  @IBAction func animateBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    fadeText(counter: &counter, duration: 2.0)
  }


  func fadeText(counter: inout Int, duration: TimeInterval) {
    if counter < sentences.count {
      if counter % 2 != 0 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
          self.label1.alpha = 0.0
          self.label2.alpha = 1.0          
        }, completion: { finished in
          if finished {
            counter += 1
            if counter <= (self.sentences.count - 1) {
              self.label1.text = self.sentences[counter]
            } else {
              return
            }
            self.fadeText(counter: &counter, duration: duration)
          }
        })
      } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
          self.label1.alpha = 1.0
          self.label2.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: { finished in
          if finished {
            counter += 1
            if counter <= (self.sentences.count - 1) {
              self.label2.text = self.sentences[counter]
            } else {
              return
            }
            self.fadeText(counter: &counter, duration: duration)
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Assumptions:

1. There is an array named `sentences` (you can alter this) on the `ViewController` that contains `String`s.
2. There is a `counter`variable that **starts at 1**
3. The `UILabel`s are overlapping in the storyboard.

Other than that you just have to call the function with the `counter` variable with an `&` operator in front, because for `fadeText` to alter the `counter` variable it needs the address, in memory, of the `counter` variable, not the value (notice the `inout` in the parameters of `fadeText`).

If you have any questions feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise creating an int variable outside the scope of the animatedText() function and simply adding 1 to this variable each time your completion block is called. You can then update the label's text to the string in the array using this int variable as the array's index each time the function is called.